# HorizontalGridView from lean back i want to keep item in center

Tags: android-layout, android-tv, leanback

I have list of item, i am using `HorizontalGridView` to display that item, i want to keep the `HorizontalGridView` in center of the screen but its not working.

Following is my code:

```
<android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

But it occupies complete width and height even-though there is less item 
Note: I am developing for android tv using `leanback` library

Comment: Can you show whole *xml layout code* and SS of your *output* ?

Comment: its easy to reproduce put relativelayout as parent and use my above code set background for the HorizontalGridView it will occupy complete view

Comment: did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `RecyclerView` if you want to center and wrap content. Actually, `HorizontalGridView` extends `RecyclerView`, so it will be easy to change to:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```